# Using jQuery to hide sub-menu's on click (only one open at a time)

Tags: jquery, menu, click, submenu

I'm having an issue trying to get the sub menus to work as I'd like. Here is my list of requirements (and what I've got so far):

- Only have one sub menu open at a time (works)
- Have clicking toggle the sub menu (not working on same item)

So the issue right now is when you click to open a sub menu, if you click the same parent anchor it won't close. The other functionality works fine though.

JS

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
        $('.sub-menu').removeClass('show');
    } else {
        $('.sub-menu').removeClass('show');
        $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Our Advantage</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Why Choose Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Affordability</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah Blah Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Technology</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blah Blah Blah</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Appointments</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu-menu-1 li.menu-item-has-children ul {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

#menu-menu-1 li.menu-item-has-children ul.show {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please include your CSS

Comment: @Michael Added to the question! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the A-Elemets children in your if-statement ( not the element itself where the listener is registered):

JS

```
$('.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next('ul').hasClass("show")) {
        $('.sub-menu').removeClass('show');
    } else {
        $('.sub-menu').removeClass('show');
        $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. I'm just starting with JS and was wondering if you could expand on what makes this work. The initial selector ".menu-item-has-children > a" would target the dropdown anchors, and then the one clicked would append "show" to the 'next' UL — because the UL is a sibling to the anchor, right?